# GeoServer (New Vector Data Source from PostGIS)

Tags: postgis, geoserver, vector

I have this error on GeoServer:

> Error creating data store, check the parameters. Error message: Unable
> to obtain connection: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The
> authentication type 10 is not supported. Check that you have
> configured the pg_hba.conf file to include the client's IP address or
> subnet, and that it is using an authentication scheme supported by the
> driver.)

How do I solve this error?

Comment: Did you check your pg_hba file like the message says? Please add the relevant line in your question

Comment: Yes , but I still have the same issue

Comment: Please add the relevant line in your question - we need to know what you have set as your authentication type

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a mismatch between the PostgreSQL JDBC driver available in GeoServer and the authentication setup in PostgreSQL. I'm going to guess you upgraded to PostgreSQL 13 but have an old(er?) GeoServer release.

Options:

- Try out the latest GeoServer version available
- Re-configure your authentication to use MD5
- Keep the GeoServer version, and replace the JDBC driver found in `WEB-INF/lib`. Mind, no guarantee it will work, it's going to be an untested combination.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64210167/unable-to-connect-to-postgress-db-due-to-the-authentication-type-10-is-not-suppo